# how to display date difference using javascript and disable old dates

Tags: javascript, datepicker

i have a problem with my js

i have to find the difference between two days and have to disable the past dates too..

i tried many scripts but all have these functions separately.. like past disabling alone.. or date calculation.. i need both the functions combined together in my work.

i tried out some js

you can check out my js below link

```
    [http://jsfiddle.net/w5eta8rm/2/][1]
```

kindly check the link above.. i combined them both.. but unable to make it to work..

i dont need an alert function.. i need to show it as text below the datepicker.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include code in your question. In future your link may be dead and this question would not be useful for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check **[here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kriyeta/vdqtk3n2/)**

- giving days difference and printing in div down to datepicker
- combined past disabling alone and date calculation
- dateTo gets enabled when you select dateFrom

**HTML file**

```
<form method="post">
    <div height="100px">
    <br/>
    From: <input type="text" name="date_from" id="TxtFromDate" autocomplete="off" />
    To: <input type="text" name="date_to" id="TxtToDate" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 200px;" id="id_days"></div>
</form>
```

**JS file**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#TxtFromDate").datepicker({ 
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate:"+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function(selected,evnt) {
            var newDate=new Date($('#TxtFromDate').val());
            $("#TxtToDate").datepicker("destroy");
            $("#TxtToDate").datepicker({
                minDate: newDate,
                maxDate: "+60D",
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                onSelect: function(selected,evnt) {
                    var maxdate=new Date($('#TxtToDate').val());
                    var mindate=new Date($('#TxtFromDate').val());
                    var difference_ms=maxdate-mindate;
                    var days = Math.floor(difference_ms/(1000*60*60*24));
                    $('#id_days').empty();
                    $('#id_days').append("Diff date is: " + days).show();
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: hi sir, thanks for the code. it is working well. but it is not resetting when we try to select the date again.

Comment: @Purushoth Here you go. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var $datepicker1 =  $( "#datepicker1" );
var $datepicker2 =  $( "#datepicker2" );

$datepicker1.datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+60D",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
    }
});

$datepicker2.datepicker({

    onClose: function() {
        var fromDate = $datepicker1.datepicker('getDate');
        var toDate = $datepicker2.datepicker('getDate');
        // date difference in millisec
        var diff = new Date(toDate - fromDate);
        // date difference in days
        var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;

        if (fromDate > toDate) {
            $("#datepicker1").val('');
            $("#datepicker2").val('');
            alert("From Date Is Less Than To Date");
            $('input:text[id$=id_days]').val();
        }
        else {
            $('input:text[id$=id_days]').val(days);
        }  

    }
});
});


<input type="text" name="noof_days" id="id_days" autocomplete="off" class="back"  onkeyup="total()" style="border:none; color:#333;" />
```